# How to make Postfix route mails through sender-specific relay instead of smarthost?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, redhat

I need all emails sent from a specific email address, `example@example.com` to get routed through a specific smart host (our 365 tenant).  I've got it set up by setting in main.cf:

```
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_by_sender
```

where it is defined like so in relay_by_sender:

```
example@example.com        [example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com]:25
```

after that was set, I ran `postmap /etc/postfix/relay_by_sender` and then restarted postfix.

When I send emails from `example@example.com` through postfix, they still get routed by the rule defined in my `transport` file which sends all emails outbound through another smarthost.

I think I am running into a rule precedence issue, but not sure how to resolve.  Any help  is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could likely avoid the transport rule that takes precedence, by using your `relay_by_sender` file for everything:

```
# Exceptions
example@example.com        [example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com]:25
# Defaults
@example.com               [smarthost.example.net]:25
@example.org               [smarthost.example.net]:25
```

The first match will count.